# Download textarea content as batch file onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, batch-file

I'm having trouble **`downloading the textarea content on the click of a link`**.
Actually I want it to be able to store the following : 
**java -jar (textarea content).jar**

and I want the `download` to be of the name `'info.bat'` . So, I tried doing it with text file but the issue is it's storing the entire document instead of only the textarea content. When I tried it out in JSFiddle it's giving an error message asking me to post it to the server and then to download it. I don't want to send the data to the server, is there any way out ?
[JsFddile](https://jsfiddle.net/aishwarya26/2vh7f0ja/)

This is the HTML code -

```
<textarea id="textbox" rows="1" cols="30"></textarea>   
<a href="#" download="info.txt" class="button">Download</a>
```

Js -

```
var anchor = document.querySelector('a#button');
var textbox = document.querySelector('#textbox');
anchor.onclick = function () {
    anchor.href = (textbox.value);
    anchor.download = 'info.txt';
};
```

**EDIT :**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Top</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
        <style type="text/css">
            body
            {
                background-color: #fff;
            }
            textarea
            {
                position: absolute;
                top: 30%;
                left: 48%;
            }
            a
            {
                position: absolute;
                top:50%;
                left: 50%;
                text-align: center;
                text-decoration: none;
            }
            a:link, a:visited 
            {
                display: block;
                font-weight: bold;
                background-color: #98bf21;
                color: #fff;
                border:2px solid #98bf21;
                width: 120px;
                height: 20px;
                border-radius: 25px;
                text-align: center;
                padding: 4px;
                text-decoration: none;
            }

            a:hover, a:active 
            {
                color: #000;
                background-color: #fff;
                border:2px solid #98bf21;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <textarea id="textbox" rows="1" cols="30"></textarea>
        <a href="#" download="info.txt" class="button">Download</a>
        <!--<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js" ></script>-->
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        var anchor = document.querySelector('a.button');
        var textbox = document.querySelector('#textbox');
        anchor.onclick = function () 
        {
            var blob = new Blob([textbox.value], {type: "text/plain;charset=utf-8"});
            saveAs(blob, "info.txt");
            //window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob(blob, 'msSaveBlobOrOpenBlob_testFile.txt');
        };
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    <textarea id="textbox" rows="1" cols="30"></textarea>
    <a href="#" download="info.txt" class="button" id="button">Download</a>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var anchor = document.querySelector('a#button');
        anchor.onclick = function(e) {

            var textbox_text = document.querySelector('#textbox').value;

            var textbox_file = new Blob([textbox_text], {"type":"application/bat"});  
            anchor.href = URL.createObjectURL(textbox_file);
            anchor.download = "newtext.txt";
        };
    </script>
```

By adding the ID attribute as button, I was able to download the content and not the whole HTML code.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [FileSaver.js](http://eligrey.com/demos/FileSaver.js/) to download files you created. 
I think this is what you want.

Check here: https://jsfiddle.net/2vh7f0ja/6/

```
var anchor = document.querySelector('a.button');
var textbox = document.querySelector('#textbox');
anchor.onclick = function () {
    var blob = new Blob([`java -jar ${textbox.value}.jar`], {type: "text/plain;charset=utf-8"});
    saveAs(blob, "a.bat");
};
```

**Entire HTML:**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Top</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
        <style type="text/css">
            body
            {
                background-color: #fff;
            }
            textarea
            {
                position: absolute;
                top: 30%;
                left: 48%;
            }
            a
            {
                position: absolute;
                top:50%;
                left: 50%;
                text-align: center;
                text-decoration: none;
            }
            a:link, a:visited 
            {
                display: block;
                font-weight: bold;
                background-color: #98bf21;
                color: #fff;
                border:2px solid #98bf21;
                width: 120px;
                height: 20px;
                border-radius: 25px;
                text-align: center;
                padding: 4px;
                text-decoration: none;
            }

            a:hover, a:active 
            {
                color: #000;
                background-color: #fff;
                border:2px solid #98bf21;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <textarea id="textbox" rows="1" cols="30"></textarea>
        <a href="#" download="info.txt" class="button">Download</a>
        <!--<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js" ></script>-->
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/FileSaver.js/2014-11-29/FileSaver.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        var anchor = document.querySelector('a.button');
        var textbox = document.querySelector('#textbox');
        anchor.onclick = function () 
        {
            var blob = new Blob([textbox.value], {type: "text/plain;charset=utf-8"});
            saveAs(blob, "info.txt");
            //window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob(blob, 'msSaveBlobOrOpenBlob_testFile.txt');
        };
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: but how does it allow me to save a .bat file ?

Comment: the second parameter of savaAs function is file name, you can change it arbitrarily.

Comment: The only issue that i'm facing is when I run the fiddle it is storing the textbox content but when i run my html page on localhost it is storing the entire code. Any idea why ?

Comment: As a side remark, it is important to note the file API is not supported the same on all browsers so if you want to support IE9 or under you'll need to have a fallback using server-side code. working locally, there might also be security restrictions causing trouble, it would be better to test on a server (even a local server)

Comment: I've edited the question. If you could help me figure out the reason as to why the entire program is getting downloaded, it would be of much help.

Comment: You should remove the `download` attribute in the `a`, and then add the script FileSaver.js library in your file. I'll edit my post and put the entire html code.

Answer (score 0):

The following would work :

```
var anchor = document.querySelector('a#button');

anchor.onclick = function(e) {

    var textbox_text = document.querySelector('#textbox').value;

    var textbox_file = new Blob([textbox_text], {"type":"application/bat"});  
    anchor.href = URL.createObjectURL(textbox_file);
    anchor.download = "yourfilename.bat";
};
```

Comment: Sadly, even in this the entire code is getting saved when I run it on localhost.

Comment: Yes the entire HTML page